# need to fix three overlapping divs

Tags: html

i have 3 divs, 2 are on sides fixed positions(left sidebar, and right sidebar), and middle one (middle content div) for content, every time resizing window they're overlap each other.

FOR THE CODE:
http://jsfiddle.net/4RPFa/3698/

WEBSITE:
http://www.highclassgastro.ic.cz\

```
    <div class="LeftFloat">
    <div class="VA">
**LEFT SIDEBAR**
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
**MIDDLE CONTENT DIV**
    </div>
    <div class="RightFloat">
    <div class="VA">
**RIGHT SIDEBAR**
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="language">
    <div class="VA">
    <img src="" alt="SK"/> | <img src="" alt="EN" />
    </div>
    </div>
```

I STRUGGLED I CANNOT MOVE FURTHER,
1. how to make it not to overlap each other please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample on how you can keep 3 divs without overlapping : http://jsfiddle.net/w3tK6/2/
and i've added a div in the main section with minimum width of `300px` , you must play with `min-width` on sidebars and main-content so they will have some minimal width and they won't overlap.

Please mind that this is not an easy task and will take time to get the values right fot your specific case.

If you want your website to look good on all screens you should read up on responsive web design and maybe try to incorporate a responsive css framework. there are few good out there, but the most popular ones are [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

Comment: can you please try to edit my codes, because that what you just adviced, i tried, didnt help :/

Comment: and in your code isnt fixed position which has to remain

Comment: @user3554046 no, this isn't a site where anyone will fix anything for you. I've showed you a way to fix it, now you must work hard to make it work. If you cannot do that hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: if you could only help little more, i´ve tried a lot of thing, didnt work :(